# Бот не отправляет сообщение пользователю в лс при заходе на сервер

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет! Имеется идея сделать так, чтобы при заходе пользователя на сервер бот отправлял ему в лс какое-либо сообщение. Я нашел ответ, но он не работает. Может в настройках самого дискорд бота надо что-то изменить. Вот мой код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await bot.fetch_user(user_id=member.id).send('Добро пожаловать на сервер!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно вызывать **fetch_user()**. **send()** можно вызвать сразу у аргумента этой функции (т.к. это и есть объект участника который присоединился).

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Добро пожаловать на сервер!')
```

Насколько я помню, в настройках бота также нужно включить данный intent.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но оказывается у меня в коде не было `intents.members = True`